# grid.arrange with QICharts

Tags: r

I am trying to arrange multiple charts from qicharts. With some work I got it so `grid.arrange` would do anything, but it just shows the last item as opposed to both.

```
library(qicharts)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
y <- rnorm(24, 12, 3)
a <- qic(y,chart="i")
b <- qic(y,chart="mr")
grid.arrange(grob(plot(a)),grob(plot(b)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qicharts:::plot.qic` suggests that it relies on base graphics, so the drawing happens immediately on the device and the plot itself is not stored. You could use base functions such as par(mfrow) to arrange multiple plots side by side, or convert those base graphics objects to grob e.g. with the gridGraphics package.

Alternatively, the trellis-based function `tcc` might produce similar output, and can be used with grid.arrange,

```
grid.arrange(tcc(rnorm(24)), tcc(rnorm(24)))
```

Comment: I installed gridGraphics and tried running `grid.echo()`. tcc seems to work better as it uses ggplots. thanks for that point